# Cómo reemplazar los caracteres de una cadena por otros?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

He estado haciendo una calculadora en python con tkinter y tengo el siguiente problema. La calculadora es completamente funcional, pero a la hora de multiplicar envés de aparecer una "x" aparece un "*" y eso no se ve muy bien.
 Aqui una imagen para que vean a qué me refiero:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero que envés de ese "*" aparezca una "x".

El código:

```
import tkinter as tk

def btn_click(numbers):

    global operador

    operador=operador + str(numbers)
    var.set(operador)

def btn_clear_display():

    global operador

    operador=""
    var.set(operador)

def btn_equals_input():
    global operador
    try:
       sumup=str(eval(operador))
    except ZeroDivisionError:
       operador="0"
       var.set(operador)
       operador = ""
    else:
       var.set(sumup)   
       operador = sumup

def btn_erase():
    global operador
    operador = operador[:temp - 1]
    var.set(operador)

ventana = tk.Tk()
ventana.title("")
ventana.geometry('205x250')

operador=""

var = tk.StringVar()

temp = len(operador)


display = tk.Label(ventana, bg = "white" ,textvariable = var, width = 20, anchor = "e").place(x = 20, y = 20)

b1 = tk.Button(ventana, text = "1", command=lambda:btn_click(1), fg = "black", width = 3).place(x = 20, y = 80)
b2 = tk.Button(ventana, text = "2", command=lambda:btn_click(2), fg = "black", width = 3).place(x = 55, y = 80)
b3 = tk.Button(ventana, text = "3", command=lambda:btn_click(3), fg = "black", width = 3).place(x = 90, y = 80) 
b4 = tk.Button(ventana, text = "4", command=lambda:btn_click(4), fg = "black", width = 3).place(x = 20, y = 115)
b5 = tk.Button(ventana, text = "5", command=lambda:btn_click(5), fg = "black", width = 3).place(x = 55, y = 115)
b6 = tk.Button(ventana, text = "6", command=lambda:btn_click(6), fg = "black", width = 3).place(x = 90, y = 115)
b7 = tk.Button(ventana, text = "7", command=lambda:btn_click(7), fg = "black", width = 3).place(x = 20, y = 150)
b8 = tk.Button(ventana, text = "8", command=lambda:btn_click(8), fg = "black", width = 3).place(x = 55, y = 150)
b9 = tk.Button(ventana, text = "9", command=lambda:btn_click(9), fg = "black", width = 3).place(x = 90, y = 150)
b0 = tk.Button(ventana, text = "0", command=lambda:btn_click(0), fg = "black", width = 3).place(x = 55, y = 185)

boton_suma = tk.Button(ventana, text = "+", command=lambda:btn_click("+"), fg = "black", width = 2).place(x = 130, y = 80)
boton_resta = tk.Button(ventana, text = "-", command=lambda:btn_click("-"), fg = "black", width = 2).place(x = 155, y = 80)
boton_multi = tk.Button(ventana, text = "x", command=lambda:btn_click("*"), fg = "black", width = 2).place(x = 130, y = 115)
boton_divi = tk.Button(ventana, text = "/", command=lambda:btn_click("/"), fg = "black", width = 2).place(x = 155, y = 115)
boton_elevar = tk.Button(ventana, text = "elevar", command=lambda:btn_click("**"), fg = "black", width = 5).place(x = 130, y = 150)
boton_equals = tk.Button(ventana, text = "=", command=btn_equals_input, fg = "black", width = 5).place(x = 130, y = 185)
boton_clear = tk.Button(ventana, text = "C", command=btn_clear_display, fg = "black", width = 3).place(x = 20, y = 185)
boton_erase = tk.Button(ventana, text = "<--", command=btn_erase, fg = "black", width = 3).place(x = 90, y = 185)       

ventana.mainloop()
```

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Si reemplazas en ésta linea:
 
boton_multi = tk.Button(ventana, text = "x", command=lambda:btn_click("*"), fg = "black", width = 2).place(x = 130, y = 115)

por ésto:

boton_multi = tk.Button(ventana, text = "x", command=lambda:btn_click("x"), fg = "black", width = 2).place(x = 130, y = 115)     que sucede?

Comment: sucede que python no reconoce a x como multiplicación.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero en el texto del boton coloca una 'x'

Quedaría así:

```
boton_multi = tk.Button(ventana, text = "x", command=lambda:btn_click("x"), fg = "black", width = 2).place(x = 130, y = 115)
```

esto agrega una x cada vez que se clickee el boton.

ahora lo que debes hacer es que cuando llamas a la función `btn_equals_input()` usar el método `replace(old_value, new_value)` el cual reemplaza todos los anteriores valores de la cadena por los nuevos, esta función quedaría así:

```
def btn_equals_input():
    global operador
    # la variable operador sera cambiada por el mismo 
    # contenido de operador pero con * en lugar de x
    operador = operador.replace('x', '*')
    try:
       sumup=str(eval(operador))
    except ZeroDivisionError:
       operador="0"
       var.set(operador)
       operador = ""
    else:
       var.set(sumup)   
       operador = sumup
```

luego todo el código quedaría así:

```
import tkinter as tk

def btn_click(numbers):

    global operador
    operador = operador + str(numbers)
    var.set(operador)

def btn_clear_display():

    global operador

    operador=""
    var.set(operador)

def btn_equals_input():
    global operador
    operador = operador.replace('x', '*')
    try:
       sumup=str(eval(operador))
    except ZeroDivisionError:
       operador="0"
       var.set(operador)
       operador = ""
    else:
       var.set(sumup)   
       operador = sumup

def btn_erase():
    global operador
    operador = operador[:temp - 1]
    var.set(operador)

ventana = tk.Tk()
ventana.title("")
ventana.geometry('205x250')

operador=""

var = tk.StringVar()

temp = len(operador)


display = tk.Label(ventana, bg = "white" ,textvariable = var, width = 20, anchor = "e").place(x = 20, y = 20)

b1 = tk.Button(ventana, text = "1", command=lambda:btn_click(1), fg = "black", width = 3).place(x = 20, y = 80)
b2 = tk.Button(ventana, text = "2", command=lambda:btn_click(2), fg = "black", width = 3).place(x = 55, y = 80)
b3 = tk.Button(ventana, text = "3", command=lambda:btn_click(3), fg = "black", width = 3).place(x = 90, y = 80) 
b4 = tk.Button(ventana, text = "4", command=lambda:btn_click(4), fg = "black", width = 3).place(x = 20, y = 115)
b5 = tk.Button(ventana, text = "5", command=lambda:btn_click(5), fg = "black", width = 3).place(x = 55, y = 115)
b6 = tk.Button(ventana, text = "6", command=lambda:btn_click(6), fg = "black", width = 3).place(x = 90, y = 115)
b7 = tk.Button(ventana, text = "7", command=lambda:btn_click(7), fg = "black", width = 3).place(x = 20, y = 150)
b8 = tk.Button(ventana, text = "8", command=lambda:btn_click(8), fg = "black", width = 3).place(x = 55, y = 150)
b9 = tk.Button(ventana, text = "9", command=lambda:btn_click(9), fg = "black", width = 3).place(x = 90, y = 150)
b0 = tk.Button(ventana, text = "0", command=lambda:btn_click(0), fg = "black", width = 3).place(x = 55, y = 185)

boton_suma = tk.Button(ventana, text = "+", command=lambda:btn_click("+"), fg = "black", width = 2).place(x = 130, y = 80)
boton_resta = tk.Button(ventana, text = "-", command=lambda:btn_click("-"), fg = "black", width = 2).place(x = 155, y = 80)
boton_multi = tk.Button(ventana, text = "x", command=lambda:btn_click("x"), fg = "black", width = 2).place(x = 130, y = 115)
boton_divi = tk.Button(ventana, text = "/", command=lambda:btn_click("/"), fg = "black", width = 2).place(x = 155, y = 115)
boton_elevar = tk.Button(ventana, text = "elevar", command=lambda:btn_click("**"), fg = "black", width = 5).place(x = 130, y = 150)
boton_equals = tk.Button(ventana, text = "=", command=btn_equals_input, fg = "black", width = 5).place(x = 130, y = 185)
boton_clear = tk.Button(ventana, text = "C", command=btn_clear_display, fg = "black", width = 3).place(x = 20, y = 185)
boton_erase = tk.Button(ventana, text = "<--", command=btn_erase, fg = "black", width = 3).place(x = 90, y = 185)       

ventana.mainloop()
```

Comment: Anduve buscando esa misma funcion de replace pero no la encontraba. Funciona perfecto gracias. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que remplazar "*" por "X" en "boton_multi"

Quedando de esta manera:
boton_multi = tk.Button(ventana, text = "x", command=lambda:btn_click("X"), fg = "black", width = 2).place(x = 130, y = 115)

espero que te funciones 
saludos,